# How to return a value of object that's being done operation of on Kotlin (similar to double dot operator in Javascript)?

Tags: kotlin

In Javascript, there's an operator like double dot (..) where you can do an operation on the said object, and then return the modified object altogether instead of returning the function result.

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
return a..push(4) // returned data: array of [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there any such operator in Kotlin? I want to change:

```
var a = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
a.add(4)
return a
```

into:

```
var a = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
return (a..add(4))
```

or something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want is **apply** operator

> Calls the specified function block with this value as its receiver and
> returns this value.

```
var a = arrayListOf(1,2,3)
a = a.apply {add(4) }
println(a)
// [1,2,3,4]
```

further reading:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html